# %spark.r interpreter is not working in Zeppelin 0.6.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr, apache-zeppelin

I am having Spark 1.6.2 cluster with Hadoop YARN, Oozie. I have installed Zeppelin 0.6.1(Binary package with all interpreters: zeppelin-0.6.1-bin-all.tgz). When I am trying to use SparkR script with %spark.r interpreter,

```
%spark.r
# Creating SparkConext and connecting to Cloudant DB
sc1 <- sparkR.init(sparkEnv = list("cloudant.host"="host_name","cloudant.username"="user_name","cloudant.password"="password", "jsonstore.rdd.schemaSampleSize"="-1"))

# Database to be connected to extract the data
database <- "sensordata"
# Creating Spark SQL Context
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
# Creating DataFrame for the "sensordata" Cloudant DB
sensorDataDF <- read.df(sqlContext, database, header='true', source = "com.cloudant.spark",inferSchema='true')
# Get basic information about the DataFrame(sensorDataDF)
printSchema(sensorDataDF)
```

I am getting the following error(log):

```
ERROR [2016-08-25 03:28:37,336] (
{Thread-77}
JobProgressPoller.java[run]:54) - Can not get or update progress
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getProgress(RemoteInterpreter.java:373)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getProgress(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:111)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.progress(Paragraph.java:237)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.JobProgressPoller.run(JobProgressPoller.java:51)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_getProgress(RemoteInterpreterService.java:296)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.getProgress(RemoteInterpreterService.java:281)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getProgress(RemoteInterpreter.java:370)
... 3 more
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try setting spark master as local[2], if that works, you might be missing few environmental variables in env file

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same similar issue after migrating to 0.6.1. The issue is Zeppelin is built with scala 2.11 and Apache Spark 1.6.2 is built with scala 2.10. 
You need to build spark 1.6.x with scala 2.11 or migrate your spark code to 2.0.0

Comment: I'm facing this issue right now with Spark2.0.0 and scala 2.11.6. and zeppelin 0.6.2

Comment: any updates on this? I am having this issue with Spark 2.0.1 and Zeppelin 0.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Setting local[2] in the interpreter section fixed my issues. This was originally suggested by vgunnu

"Try setting spark master as local[2], if that works, you might be missing few environmental variables in env file – vgunnu Aug 25 at 4:37"